# Opening the properties view as wizard dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is there any way to open the properties view in the wizard .
Requirement:We are creating a button in the editor to open the wizard and in that wizard i want the properties view to be added.
(OR)
Can we open the view on clicking the button i.e popping up the view on click of button in editor page and closing it if the cursor come out of the view

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't show any view in a dialog (including wizards)